# React - Using a for-loop inside JSX

Tags: reactjs

In the following React component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const List = () => {
  const docLimit = 2;
  const maxColNumber = 6;

  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  const [beginAfter, setBeginAfter] = useState(0);


  return (
    <>
      <div className='collection'>
        <div className='collection__set' onClick={() => setBeginAfter(0)}>
          First 2 data
        </div>
        <div
          className='collection__set'
          onClick={() => setBeginAfter(docLimit * 1)}
        >
          Next 2 data
        </div>
        <div
          className='collection__set'
          onClick={() => setBeginAfter(docLimit * 2)}
        >
          Next 2 data
        </div>
        <div
          className='collection__set'
          onClick={() => setBeginAfter(docLimit * 3)}
        >
          Next 2 data
        </div>
      </div>

      <ul className='list'>
        {cards.map((card) => (
          <li key={card.id} className='list__item'>
            <DeleteCard card={card} />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default List;
```

I want to use a loop to output this part:

```
<div className='collection'>
    <div className='collection__set' onClick={() => setBeginAfter(0)}>
      First 2 data
    </div>
    <div
      className='collection__set'
      onClick={() => setBeginAfter(docLimit * 1)}
    >
      Next 2 data
    </div>
    <div
      className='collection__set'
      onClick={() => setBeginAfter(docLimit * 2)}
    >
      Next 2 data
    </div>
    <div
      className='collection__set'
      onClick={() => setBeginAfter(docLimit * 3)}
    >
      Next 2 data
    </div>
  </div>
```

But it doesn't matter what I try, it doesn't work.

I tried this:

```
const renderMenu = () => {
    const menu = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < maxColNumber; i++) {
      menu.push(
          <div
            className='collection__set'
            onClick={setBeginAfter(docLimit * i)}
          >
            Next 2 data
          </div>
      );
    }
    return (
        <div className='collection'>menu</div>
        )
  };
```

But it didn't work.
Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insted of using `for`, you can use `map`.

Try this method:

```
const Menu = () => Array(maxColNumber / 2).fill().map((_, i) => {
    const onClick = () => setBeginAfter(docLimit * i)
    return (
        <div className='collection'>
            <div
                className='collection__set'
                onClick={onClick}
                >
                Next 2 data
            </div>
        </div>
    )
})
// later in your code , just add the tag
<Menu />
```

Comment: You can use ```useMemo``` if the ```maxColNumber``` doesn't change, and you can keep it inside the functional component. This way it won't re-render each time. You can read more about ```useMemo``` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

Comment: maxColNumber will change. @CevaComic, thanks for your solution. However, your solution creates 6 divs, instead of 4. i variable should be increased by 1 in each loop. I don't think that it does increase in your solution.

Comment: I thought ```maxColNumber``` is the number of divs you want, in this case just replace it with ```maxColNumber / 2```. The point is that inside ```Array()``` you need the number of iterations. And if it changes is not that much a problem, you can add it to ```useMemo``` as a dependency and it will re-render only when that value changes.

Comment: @user1941537, I edited the post. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Yes, it's working now. I only had to change Array(maxColNumber / 2) to Array(maxColNumber / 2 + 1). 1000 thanks. One last question though. What is i in your code. I don't see that i is declared anywhere in your code.

Comment: The i is declared in the ```map```. ```map(_,i)```, that's the index of the iteration. [More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), you don't need to declare it yourself, is provided by ```map```.

Comment: Clever solution. But what is the _ in map(_, i) ?

Comment: @question: if you read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) , the ```_``` should be the name of the current element. Since the current element in this case is ```undefined```, and we don't do anything with it, it's good practice using an underscore.